# only remove integers within bracket from df column - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to remove brackets with integers only from a df column. If it's an object than I'm hoping to keep it. Using below, there are certain rows that have two brackets. I only want to remove brackets that are all integers.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'col': ['Bear  (123)', 'Dog (No 2a)  (1502)', 'Cat Dog (No 7b)  (16772)', 'Bear  (123)']})

df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace(r"\(.*\)","")
```

intended out:

```
               col
0             Bear  
1      Dog (No 2a)
2  Cat Dog (No 7b)
3             Bear
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace(r'\s*\(\d*\)', '', regex=True)
```

output:

```
               col
0             Bear
1      Dog (No 2a)
2  Cat Dog (No 7b)
3             Bear
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9MF5Zu/1)

```
\s*    # match spaces (optional)
\(     # match literal (
\d*    # match zero or more digits (use \d+ to force at least 1 digit)
\)     # match literal )
```

*NB. use `regex=True` to avoid the future warning.*

Answer (score 1):

Use `\s*` for match optionally spaces before and after brackets, `\d+` for match integers:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace(r"\s*\(\d+\)\s*","", regex=True)
print (df)
               col
0             Bear
1      Dog (No 2a)
2  Cat Dog (No 7b)
3             Bear
```